# PyQt: QWebView.print_( QPrinter() ) gives blank PDF file

Tags: python, pdf, pyqt, qwebview

Hello there everybody!

In the tool I develop I need a function of generatin' simple PDF raports. Nothing spetial. 2 png pictures on top, a bit of text and a table below.
I've figured out the easiest way will be to create HTML file and then printing it to PDF using PyQt4. Unfortunatlly something in my code works wrong.

More in coments within the code

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *

web = QWebView()
web.load(QUrl(r'file:///H:/.../table.htm'))
web.show() ### HERE IT WORKS! - IT SHOWS MY HTML FILE CORRECTLY

printer = QPrinter()
printer.setPageSize(QPrinter.A4)
printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)
printer.setOutputFileName(r"H:\...\file.pdf")

web.print_(printer) ### HERE IS THE PROBLEM. PDF FILE IS CREATED INDEED.
                    ### IT SEEMS TO BE A4, BUT COMPLETLY EMPTY. :-/
```

Created PDF file looks like this - [EMPTY PDF WITH SOME EMPTY OBJECT INSIDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ke0ch.png)

If somebody knows the solution I'd be very thankful.

Good Day then!

Janek

Comment: If you just need to generate a PDF from HTML, take a look at [weasyprint](https://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#quickstart). You can do it in one line without all the PyQt stuff.

Comment: I'd like to use it, but could you tell me what to do if I build just a plugin to the bigger software. I would like to use weasyprint library, but don't want to force user to install it. Could I somehow copy it to the catalog of plugin and import modules?

Comment: It should be possible to bundle everything up, but you would need to track down all the required dependencies, keeping in mind that some of which are going to be platform specific. Your PyQt approach may be better if you don't want to worry about external dependencies.

Comment: You should probably use loadFinished() to ensure the web view has actually loaded the content before it gets rendered to the QPrinter. See [this example on github](https://gist.github.com/creotiv/1585360).

Comment: Simon, you were right. I copied the solution from that link and it worked.
It requires to make a class for QWebView, but that works. :-)